# i install all package regarding flask-mysqldb but occurs this error version python 3.5

Tags: flask, mysql-python

> (flask) C:\Users\tejas\Documents\flask\flask\Scripts>python -m pip list
>   Package                Version
>
> ---
>
> Click                  7.0
>   Flask                  1.1.1
>   Flask-MySQL            1.4.0
>   Flask-MySQLdb          0.2.0
>   itsdangerous           1.1.0
>   Jinja2                 2.10.3
>   MarkupSafe             1.1.1
>   mysql-connector        2.2.9
>   mysql-connector-python 8.0.18
>   mysqlclient            1.4.6
>   pip                    19.3.1
>   protobuf               3.11.1
>   PyMySQL                0.9.3
>   setuptools             42.0.2
>   six                    1.13.0
>   Werkzeug               0.16.0
>   wheel                  0.33.6
>   AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'connection' and
>   ImportError: No module named 'flask_MySQLdb'

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> Usage
>
> Initialize the extension :
>
> ```py
> from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
> mysql = MySQL()
> mysql.init_app(app)
> ```